# Types of wake locks in android?

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

How many types of wake locks in android and what are they?

1) Wake lock
2) WiFi lock

do we have any other locks other than above 2?

do we have any lock for avoiding the 3G modem (Data connection) to avoid it from going to sleep mode due to inactivity?

Please let me know if any have idea on the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do we have any other locks other than above 2?

Not really.

> do we have any lock for avoiding the 3G modem (Data connection) to avoid it from going to sleep mode due to inactivity?

No, because the mobile data connection does not go into sleep mode. While the mobile data connection does [go through various power states](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html), it automatically switches between them as necessary, and if you have an outstanding connection, it will not go into standby.

Comment: Did my round of googling as well :).